# Two things 1. webp images on windows photo viewers were darker. 2. Second one is written in the post it didn't fit in the title bar

Tags: webp

I tried to find solution to fix my first problem and followed [this](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/webp-appear-dark-windows-photo-viewer/) suggestion. Unfortunately after I uninstall webp with Powershell, it doesn't display thumbnails or images anymore even after I reinstall google's webp codec again.

I had one problem before, now I have two:

1. Is this darkness problem even fixable?
2. How can I get webp to work back on windows photo viewer and explorer to display thumbnails?

Reinstall instruction in this article didn't work. Gave me "Can't find path C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WebpImageExtension_1.0.32731.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" error.
*Of course opened powershell as administrator.*

**What I've  tried so far:**

- followed the instruction in the article reinstalled WebpCodecSetup and that didn't work
- tried powershell command to reinstall webp but gave me "Can't find path C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WebpImageExtension_1.0.32731.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" error
- uninstalled reinstalled WebpCodecSetup

I thought it would work after reboot and still didn't work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You being bot or not doesn't matter, I'll reply you anyway. It's specific enough.

Comment: Hello, this will be closed in the current state because it's asking multiple not too related questions. Only one specific question per post, so split them please.